# Using grep and mediainfo together

Tags: grep, find, sort

I'm trying to build a list of movies with the metadata name and the file path. This is my statement so far:

```
find ~/Videos/Movies/ -type f -exec mediainfo {} \; | grep -E 'Movie name|Complete name' | sort > ~/Videos/movies.txt
```

It puts all the data I want in my text file but it arranges it in a single sorted list with the name and path being treated as two separate entries in different places on the queue. How should I change the statement to arrange the list - sorted by movie name but with the path and name together? Thx.

Current output eg:

```
Complete name                            : /home/matthew/Videos/Movies/1-a/10RillingtonPlace.m4v
Complete name                            : /home/matthew/Videos/Movies/1-a/12AngryMen.m4v
Complete name                            : /home/matthew/Videos/Movies/1-a/12YearsASlave.m4v
Movie name                               : 10 Rillington Place
Movie name                               : 12 Angry Men
Movie name                               : 12 Years a Slave
```

What I'd like to see:

```
Movie name                               : 10 Rillington Place
Complete name                            : /home/matthew/Videos/Movies/1-a/10RillingtonPlace.m4v
Movie name                               : 12 Angry Men
Complete name                            : /home/matthew/Videos/Movies/1-a/12AngryMen.m4v
Movie name                               : 12 Years a Slave
Complete name                            : /home/matthew/Videos/Movies/1-a/12YearsASlave.m4v
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an example we can use to understand what you are asking and test our solutions. We need to see an example of the output of either ` mediainfo` or, at least `mediainfo | grep -E 'Movie name|Complete name'` so we know what you are dealing with. Then, show us the output you would like to get from that example. Also mention your operating system since that affects the flavor of tools like `grep` and `find`.

Comment: @terdon: ... or `{g,}awk`. ;-))